# Spring Boot with OAuth2 behind reverse proxy

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, reverse-proxy, oauth2client

I'm new with Spring Security and trying to develop Spring Boot app with Google login using OAuth2 which runs under hostname:8080. This app is behind Apache reverse proxy server https://url.com.

Spring Boot version 2.1.0

Spring Security version 5.1.1

build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    implementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-client")
    implementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-jose")
}
```

application.yml:

```
oauth2:
  client:
    registration:
      google:
        clientId: <clientId>
        clientSecret: <clientSecret> 
        scope: profile, email, openid

server:
  use-forward-headers: true
  servlet:
    session:
      cookie:
        http-only: false
```

Spring Security config:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf()
                .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2Login();
    }
  }
```

1. I request https://url.com
2. Get redirected to https://accounts.google.com/signin/oauth/
3. When authenticated get redirected back to
   [https://url.com/login/oauth2/code/google?state={state}&code={code}&scope=openid+email+profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fplus.me&authuser=0&session_state={session_state}&prompt=none](https://url.com/login/oauth2/code/google?state=%7Bstate%7D&code=%7Bcode%7D&scope=openid%20email%20profile%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fplus.me&authuser=0&session_state=%7Bsession_state%7D&prompt=none) which timed out with error:

> [invalid_token_response] An error occurred while attempting to
>   retrieve the OAuth 2.0 Access Token Response: I/O error on POST
>   request for "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token": Connection
>   timed out (Connection timed out); nested exception is
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)

Is this error caused by the proxy server settings or boot app? Thanks for help.

Comment: Show your reverse-proxy configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I had to set the JVM parameters:

```
https.proxyHost=[host]
https.proxyPort=[port] 

http.proxyHost=[host]
http.proxyPort=[port]
```

Comment: Does your application run on host, which have some firewall rules to disable direct access to Internet? Why does setting JVM proxy parameter helped?